# Can software be developed in a different "human language" in C/C++?

Tags: c, locale

I am developing a test software where the user can enter a string where I must validate it as C++ variable syntax. Then I started wondering if people can develop in japanese or other idioms.

When I typed "is" on some IDE, it poped up a list with a "isascii" function. Then I wondered if I can use that function to check for the letters of the variable.

I googled and couldn't find about isascii if not on microsoft's msdn, so I guess its a windows function that use the locale of the machine?

could someone also explain a bit of this isascii and __isascii please?

edit:
what of this "is" functions should I use to check for the letter that is in the name of the variable?

Thanks and sorry my nooberish!
Joe

Comment: Do you mean language instead of idiom?

Comment: I guess. My english isn't that good. I was thinking that people could miss language of C/C++, thats why I wrote idiom, to be sure that I was talking about foreign languages. I guess the correct is language in this case?

Comment: I think by "idiom" you may mean "human language". The term "idiom" is used in programming to refer to a particular style of programming, ie. a functional programming idiom, or object oriented programming idiom. I realise that "idioma" means "language" in at least Spanish, Portuguese, and Italian.

Comment: @Greg: That would be "paradigm", not "idiom". Idioms in programming are something else: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_idiom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might find this article by Joel Spolsky helpful, if you're interested in
writing software that can deal gracefully with international languages and character
sets:

[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Edit: Upon closer reading of your question, it seems you are more interested in
whether international characters are valid to use in your C or C++ source code.
[Yes, this is possible.](http://scv.bu.edu/computation/bluegene/IBMdocs/compiler/xlc-8.0/html/language/ref/unicode_standard.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can find out about character classification, including `isascii`, by looking at the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isalpha).  Which characters are considered letters (and so on) is determined by your "locale".  I confess I always find locale settings confusing...

Answer (score 0):

The C standard doesn't consider letters that are not contained in ASCII as letters.
Thus I don't think C supports characters other than [c=='_' isalpha()][c=='_' isalnum()]* for symbol names, even though other programming languages do. So you should check for that.